# Uv strech Angle vs Area?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Hi I I would like to know , why it is different between this 2 options in my uv editor ?  in the firts Image  there is full blue, in the strech -> Area I know it is right (blue) but when I press the strecht->area as in the second picture. it is show me orange and green which is not accurate I think. 
 (consider I am trying  to make a texture atlas and the parts of my object will be snapping in the case with the geometry is the same and share the same uv space as in the images.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you absolutely sure the UV area is equal to the 3D area? just making sure...

Comment: I am working with Metric... for example one of object is 30 meters  x , y, z ...   ( 198,4252 inch ) but when I am making the texturing atlasing process  , the stretch are not bad , but the "area" is yellow and orange, I do not understand the question ,  you mean to apply the average scale? ,  yes,  I selected all the objects in the 3d viewport and also selected all the Uv's in the editor ... I make sure both selected then press "cotrol + A and then control + p